# Why does this line of code have a backslash as output?

Tags: python, string, escaping

```
>>> 'She said, "That' + "'" + 's hard to read."'
'She said, "That\'s hard to read."'
```

Why does this line of code have a backslash in the output?

Comment: I've tried `print('She said, "That' + "'" + 's hard to read."')` and get this output without a backslah: `>>>She said, "That's hard to read."`. Can you extense the explaining of your problem?

Comment: I am using IDLE. Do you think this might have something to do with it? @MrNobody33

Comment: No, that's weird, I've tried with the IDLE and got the same result `She said, "That's hard to read."`. Can you add maybe some screenshots of the output and some code?. Try this maybe:  `print('She said, \"That\'s hard to read.\"')`.

Comment: @MrNobody33 OP's talking about the representation in the REPL. I edited to clarify

Comment: @wjandrea thank for the clarification. If that's your question you may see the link that wjandrea put in his commentary. There is a good explanation about this. This happens because of `repr()` of strings.

Comment: @JacobJohnston I'm also using IDLE, and I see what you mean.